# How to kill google when i launch it with the exec command

Tags: php, windows, exec

I am currently using a PHP server on my computer, provided by the Wamp application stack, and attempting to terminate processes properly using the 'exec' function in the PHP language.

The PHP executable was launched with the following arguments: "-S localhost:8000 -t D:\wamp\www", before I viewed 'page1.php' from my machine using Mozilla Firefox.

I used the following lines of JavaScript to view my pages from the server:

```
window.open('http://localhost:8000/taskkill.php');
window.open('http://localhost:8000/launchgoogle.php');
```

taskkill.php code:

```
exec('taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T');
exec('taskkill /F /IM chromeprocess /T');
exec('tskill chrome');
```

launchgoogle.php code:

```
shell_exec('start "chromeprocess" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window -incognito www.mydomain.com');
```

A problem occurs when I open 'taskkill.php': it closes the current page opened in Google Chrome. But if I open 'launchgoogle.php' followed by taskkill.php, 'taskkill' does not work. I have to close the new page in Google Chrome, before opening 'launchgoogle.php' in Mozilla Firefox to be able to launch it again.

What can I do to kill the Google Chrome process when I launch it with the 'exec' command in PHP?

Comment: for a start you are not "killing google"

Comment: no one can help ? :D

Comment: well im not really clear on why your doing this- why you use windows, and what this has to do with php at all

Comment: i call everything by ajax, from a web page.